# Do Orks affect non-orks with their latent psyker abilities?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Orks believe that the color red makes things go faster. A basic understanding of the orks reveals that they are all latent psykers and because there are so many of them believing the same thing, they actually warp reality into making these things true. This is why, among other things, their guns work even though they are just metal tubes attached to triggers and handles, why the color red actually does make them go faster, and why things like this actually work.

[image]

My question is largely about the Orks, but the Blood Angels offer a good example. Does the color of things used/worn by non-orks matter when in the presence of a large group of orks, if at all? Would fighting orks with red armor on cause you to move faster than if you were wearing white? Would tossing a yellow grenade at them do more damage than a black one?

Comment: Guns which are just empty tubes that fire because the Orks believe in them? This has to be the stupidest bit of WH40K fluff ever.

Comment: @AndresF. you'd wonder if there are even engines in their vehicles, or do they just run on _belief_...

Comment: @AndresF. mostly yes. They also believe louder = better, and generally that holds up

Comment: last time I checked the lore, orks have latent mechanical abilities and can fashion actual working (although crude) machinery. of course a ramshackle gun put together by an ork is no match to a space marine's bolter.

Comment: I'm gonna blow your mind right now OP.
The Orks can and do affect others with their ability. My proof? "In the 41st Millenium there is only WAR"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No. Orks cannot affect anything other than their own equipment with their inherent psychic capacity. This ability was engineered into the species as a benefit for them under battle conditions. The color of other objects that are not made by Orks will not be more effective or affected at all by their gestalt ability.

> - The Orks are a biologically-engineered species, created more than 60 million Terran years ago as a warrior race originally called the Krork by the long-vanished reptilian alien species known as the Old Ones, whom the Orks refer to as the Brain Boyz. The Orks were created by the Brain Boyz to fight the Necrons and their C'tan masters in the great interstellar conflict called the War in Heaven that shattered the galactic civilisation of the Old Ones that existed prior to the rise of the Eldar.

- Orc technology is STILL technology. It is not composed of empty tubes that suddenly shoot fire because Orcs believe in it. Orcs are a genetically-engineered species whose membership includes a subgroup called **[Oddboyz](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Oddboy)** whose genetic structure includes genetic memory on how to make, use and design Orc technology.

[image]

*A Weirdboy (Orc psycher) and his gretchen defenders.*

> - Orks are thus genetically engineered to be muscular, aggressive, and none too bright; their technology is maintained by a caste of Oddboyz who possess genetically-implanted dispositions and technical knowledge that grant them unusual skill with maintaining and developing technology. However, this skill is an unconscious one preserved through genetic memories hard-wired into the Oddboyz' DNA by the Brain Boyz millions of standard years ago. Indeed, the Brain Boyz were apparently able to encode information on how to build simple machinery into the genomes of all Orks; thus Mekboyz require very little training in their function within Ork "kultur," since they understand mechanical principles at a fully instinctive level.

- Orks collective psychic abilities do not affect the technology of other species because Orks don't understand alien technology (they barely understand their own except at an instinctive level) so they are unable to change the behavior of alien technology. Their collective psychic ability is an asset and defense engineered by their creators to make Orcs more dangerous to other species.

> - Orks lack individual psychic power, being denied such abilities by the Old Ones. However, they do have a sort of collaborative, collective psychic ability, meaning that if enough Orks believe something is true, then it will actually become so, brought into power by their gestalt psychic ability. For example, Ork rockets painted yellow create bigger explosions, simply because the vast majority of Orks believe they do. This is also why much of the Orks' seemingly ramshackle technology will do terrible damage in the hands of Orks, but will cease to function when used by other races.

- This capacity to alter technology was surely created by the Brain Boys and engineered to work specifically with Orc technology. It is likely the Brain Boys would not want the Orcs to be able to do this with other technology because it might make them more difficult for the Brain Boys to control.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer Thaddeus. I didn't know they were created by the Old Ones to fight the Necron, very cool!

Comment: The Necron must have been monstrous and it appears almost everyone was at war with them at one point or another. But making Orks seems like a mistake to me. Replacing one scourge for a self-regenerating psychic plague doesn't seem like good planning to me...

Comment: Yes, but the difference between the Orks and the Necrons is the Orks just want to fight unlike the Necrons who were actually trying to exterminate all life. I also wonder if Commander Yarrick is affected by the Ork abilities seeing that he uses their technology and the Orks all believe him to be the great human warrior, and that he's nearly undefeatable.

Comment: All great information, but I fail to see how any of the points except for the 2nd to last point have any bearing on the question at hand (except for, of course, correcting some apparent misinformation on my part). Can you clarify how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: I didn't come to any conclusion. I relayed information from the Black Library texts I referenced. Orcs don't affect technology that isn't theirs. They don't understand technology, so their gestalt psychic field is a weapon ONLY when they are using their tech. Period. They don't even care what tech others are using.

Comment: As to Commander Yarrick, he is a rare exception to using Orc technology, since he had it fitted by the Imperium, if there were difficulties with its "machine spirits" they were corrected by the Techpriests. The main reason he is considered fearsome by Orcs, is because he was seen killing an Orc Warboss and taking the hand. He survived long enough to route the Orcs and his legend grew after he was captured by Orcs and then released. (The Orcs thought Yarrick would make the battle better if he was working on the other side... He did. The Imperium won.)